# How to Remove last comma of each line on csv using linux

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I need to remove the last comma of each line.

I have only one csv file, which looks like this:

```
98,N,N,N,N,S,
99,N,N,N,N,S,
101,Y,Y,Y,Y,S,
```

I have the following script, but it is not working:

```
for fname in conv2015_10_LogicalComponent_CosProfile.csv
do
   sed 's/.$//' $fname > tmp.tmp
   mv tmp.tmp $fname
done
```

Comment: "it is not working" is not very precise. Does it change anything in the file? Also what is this loop for? You know that you loop over only *one* file, right?

Comment: oh I only need to remove the last comma from one file. And I have some whitespace at the end so its not working.

Comment: `sed 's/\(.*\),/\1/' file` will remove last `,` in all lines in the file.

Comment: @yescobar1: You should update your question and add the important information about trailing spaces to your question. Questions should be answerable without reading comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this should work.

```bash
for fname in conv2015_10_LogicalComponent_CosProfile.csv
  do
    cat $fname | sed 's/.$//' > tmp.tmp
    mv tmp.tmp $fname
  done
```

Another option is if you use GNU Sed `-i` option:

then you only need to do this:

```bash
sed -i 's/.$//' filename
```

Additionaly to clarify why "." is used there instead of ",". This is regular expression which matches almost any character, so if there is ";" it would replace that as well. You be more precise you can change `.$` to `,$`.

EDIT:

I noticed that you mentioned that you actually have whitespaces at the end. So this code works, even with whitespaces. Proven on Solaris.

```bash
cat filename | sed 's/,[[:blank:]]*$//g' > tmp.tmp
mv tmp.tmp desired_filename
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion  and it did not worked.

Comment: Can you please do the following: "cat -E filename" This will output file and "$" signs at the end of line. "$" sign mark actual end of line. Maybe you have spaces at the end.

Comment: I entered `cat -E conv2015_10_LogicalComponent_CosProfile.csv` and got back `cat: illegal option -- E usage: cat [ -usvtebn ] [-|file] ... `

Comment: I enter a different command and see 98,N,N,N,N,$ at the end of each line

Comment: Which system do you use? Solaris, BSD...? If cat -E doesn't work then "cat -vet" should output that...

Comment: cat -vet worked for me

Comment: I am using putty to connect to our teams server box not sure what system they are using on their server box.

Comment: type "uname -a" and post the output here.

Comment: SunOS hstz1454 5.10 Generic_150400-20 sun4v sparc sun4v

Comment: You are using solaris, so I went up and turned one one solaris VM. And I noticed that you mentioned in i one comment that you have whitespace at the end. So if this is real this is deal. "cat filename | sed 's/,[[:blank:]]*$//g > tmp.tmp'". This works empirically. Don't forget to "mv tmp.tmp desired_file_name"

Comment: so like this `for fname in conv2015_10_LogicalComponent_CosProfile.csv
do
    cat $fname | sed 's/,[[:blank:]]*$//g' > tmp.tmp
    mv tmp.tmp $fname
done`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26661/discussion-between-yescobar1-and-neven).

Comment: This command removes whitespace `sed 's/ *, */,/' conv2015_10_LogicalComponent_CosProfile.csv` and this command removes the comma `sed 's/.$//' conv2015_10_LogicalComponent_CosProfile.csv` I entered it in the command line but some reason it is not working on my script

Comment: Useless use of cat - or can't you specify a file for sed in Solaris?

Answer (score 5):

Using `bash` parameter expansion :

```
while IFS= read -r line; do echo "${line%,}"; done <file.txt
```

Using `sed` :

```
sed 's/,$//' file.txt
```

Using `grep` with PCRE :

```
grep -Po '.*(?=,$)' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use use `vim` or `vi`.  The syntax is the same as `sed`.  Use ":" (colon) to enter command mode, and run `%s/,$//g`.

Comment: If this is solaris or BSD type UNIX there is no vim, only vi.

Comment: @Neven That should fix it...

Comment: Nice answer.  Also you can drop the `g` at the end--since you only want/expect one substitution per line (i.e. deleting the comma immediately next to the `$` zero-width end-of-string text anchor).

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a `,`-separated file and you want to remove the last [empty] field, what about decreasing the number of fields in one?

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} NF--' file
98,N,N,N,N,S
99,N,N,N,N,S
101,Y,Y,Y,Y,S
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work, if you have no whitespace at the end of the line, especially
carriage-return. Use `cat -vet` on the file to see where the end of line really is (it is shown by a `$`).

With some `sed` implementations, you can simplify your sed and mv into one line using the  `-i` option which updates the file `i`n-place (sort of).

- GNU, busybox, toybox `sed`, recent versions of NetBSD/OpenBSD

  ```
  sed -i -e 's/,$//' -- "$fname"
  ```
- FreeBSD `sed` or derivatives (including macos'):

  ```
  sed -i '' -e 's/,$//' -- "$fname"
  ```

That's inspired from the `-i` option of `perl`:

```
perl -pi -e 's/,$//' -- "$fname"
```

Comment: This will only work if there is GNU sed. Try to do this on Solaris.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`perl -pi -e 's/^(.*),(.+)$/$1/' conv2015_10_LogicalComponent_CosProfile.csv`

`(.*)` will match everything until the last comma and whatever comes after that( whitespace) can be matched with `(.+)`, and finally replace the whole line with the first match which is stored in `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -ne 'put .chop;'  file
```

OR:

```
~$ raku -pe 's/\,$//;'   file
```

Sample Input:

```
98,N,N,N,N,S,
99,N,N,N,N,S,
101,Y,Y,Y,Y,S,
```

Sample Output:

```
98,N,N,N,N,S
99,N,N,N,N,S
101,Y,Y,Y,Y,S
```

The code above is similar to other answers. Note if the lines actually contain trailing whitespace, you can use Raku's built-in `trim-trailing` routine, or modify the `s///` answer to accommodate:

```
~$ raku -ne 'put .trim-trailing.chop;'  file
```

OR:

```
~$ raku -pe 's/ \, \s*? $//;'  file
```

https://raku.org